# paste split pattern for ngx-chips (Angular)

Tags: regex, angular, ngx-chips

I'm trying to allow users to paste a list that is separated by , ; or | using ngx-chips.

There is an option to do this with pasteSplitPattern - [?string | RegExp]

https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips

When I try the following though, I get an error

```
[pasteSplitPattern]="[,|;]"

Parser Error: Unexpected token ,
```

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: try escaping the `,` like `[\,|;]`

Comment: Thanks.  That gives the error "Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [\]"

Comment: try changing to `/[\,|;]/`

Comment: When I try [pasteSplitPattern]="/[\,|;]/"  I get the error "Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 1 in [/[\,|;]/]"

Comment: Did it work? Looking at the repo code, it seem to support only string unless I am missing something.

Comment: Didn't work yet.  It allows regex... "pasteSplitPattern - [?string | RegExp]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following:

Define a new regex :

```
splitPattern = new RegExp('[\,\;]');
```

and then use it in your template:

```
[pasteSplitPattern]= "splitPattern"
```

Comment: Somehow neither of those works for me. Are there other properties that [pasteSplitPattern] have to combined?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem : you have to add `[addOnPaste]="true"` to make it work!

Comment: This solution only includes the separation pattern by ",". To add a new pattern you must also use [pasteSplitPattern]="splitPattern"

Answer (score 0):

use the below to separate by comma or enter

```
[separatorKeyCodes]="[32, 188]"
```